# ZF2, ByjAuthorize rules in a module.config

Tags: php, zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

I'm doing something wrong I guess, I want to limited access to a module. Only logged in user may access the tijdmachine module.

This is my module.config.php:

```
<?php

namespace Tijdmachine;

return array(
  'resource_providers' => array(
        'BjyAuthorizeProviderResourceConfig' => array(
            'tijdmachine' => array(),
        ),
    ),
    'rule_providers' => array(
        'BjyAuthorizeProviderRuleConfig' => array(
            'allow' => array(
                array(array('user'), 'tijdmachine', array('index')),
            ),
        ),
    ),

        'view_manager' => array(
            'template_path_stack' => array(__DIR__ . '/../view')
     ),

    'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Tijdmachine\Controller\IndexController' => 'Tijdmachine\Controller\IndexController',
          )
    ),


    'router' => array(
       'routes' => array(
         'tijdmachine' => array(
            'resource' => 'tijdmachine',
            'privilege' => 'index',
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
               'route'    => '/tijdmachine',
                // <---- url format module/action/id
               'constraints' => array(
                  'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                  'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                   'controller' => 'Tijdmachine\Controller\IndexController',
                    // <--- Defined as the module controller
                   'action'     => 'index',
                    // <---- Default action
                ),
            ),
         ),
      ),
    ),

);
```

I defined a resource, a privilege and named them in my route. But, if I go the the specific url, I will still see all the information without being logged in. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'resource' and 'privilege' are parameters of the [navigation containers](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.pages.html#common-page-features), not the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated in [the documentation](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/master/README.md), you need to use the class names in the config:

```
return array(
    'resource_providers' => array(
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Resource\Config' => array(
            'tijdmachine' => array(),
        ),
    ),
    'rule_providers' => array(
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Rule\Config' => array(
            'allow' => array(
                array(array('user'), 'tijdmachine', array('index')),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    ...
    'guards' => array(

        /* If this guard is specified here (i.e. it is enabled], it will block
         * access to all routes unless they are specified here.
         */
        \BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route::class => array(
            ['route' => 'tijdmachine', 'roles' => ['user']],
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Well, I indeed read that part of the docs. Tried it aswel, but no luck. Thus, I tried using your code, still, granted access.

Comment: you don't seem to have a `Role Provider` configured, and no `'default_role'`, and I'm missing a route guard config? I suggest you read through the docs again and perform every step mentioned.

Comment: vendor/bjyauthorize/config/module.config.php -> return array(
    'bjyauthorize' => array(
        // default role for unauthenticated users
        'default_role'          => 'guest',

        // default role for authenticated users (if using the
        // 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\AuthenticationIdentityProvider' identity provider)
        'authenticated_role'    => 'user',

Comment: you'll still need the guard, as I've added to the config

Comment: also, not sure about this, but maybe you need to wrap the config in a `bjyauthorize` key as it is done in the docs?

Comment: Appearantly it doesn't matter. I putted the exact code I had (with a guard indeed!) in config/autoload/byjauthorize.global.php and for one of some reason, it works now. So thank you, you did point me in some right directions!